# Add interested users to table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

So I am working on a booking system where I am posting small avaiable jobs for the kids in the community. I am not looking for a direct booking system in the sense that the user can just press the "booking button" and directly have the job. The approach i want to take is that you can SUBMIT INTEREST and then the poster of the job can accept one of the applicants.

So i have a few tables going on but the essential for the questions are these two.

```
|users|

|id   | name | age |......
```

---

```
|jobs|

|id  | date  | salary |
```

---

What i am looking for explained in it's most simplest form is that i want multiple user id´s to be stored in a column so that i can later display/controll the users connected to the job in matter.

Would very much appreciate a sultion or just as much a tip on how i would go about solving the problem.

(I am using mySQL database if that adds any value to the question)

Best regards.

Comment: You can have 1 column named **UserId** in table jobs, and can have multiple records of single job with different UserId. Whenever you need to search user based on job, just pass it in subquery, which will give you a list of user associated with that job. Use this approach if you insist on using only above mentioned 2 tables.

Answer (score 3):

That is an n:m relation. A user can be interested in multiple jobs and a job can be interesting to multiple users. You should have a third table user_jobs for this where you store one record per user interested in a job.

Something like

```
user_jobs
 userid
 jobid
 date
 status
```

Comment: Thank you very much i see this working out well. Man i love this website so much!